# excel 2007 connect to ssas 2005 cube

Tags: excel, ssas

I have created a cube (ssas 2005), and can connect to it from excel 2007. I created a connection file (.odc). How can I set up other users to connect to the cube? I am new to this. Should they connect by creating a new connection as I do (specify server, authentication, and cube) or can I send the .odc file to them so they can open it? I don't want them to connect to the server directly because there are other cubes as well. Not sure about the usage of .odc file is it for sharing connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share the .odc file. The odc file is still connecting them to the SSAS server though, just that they don't have to type in server name or cube. You also need to make sure they actually have access to the cube with their username.

Be aware that your user can see the server and initial catalog in the connection string in their connection properties in Excel if they are smart enough to look there. If you have granted them access to view other cubes or access the AS database on the server, they can use this info to go to the server and look around.

[image]

Here's a link with more info on .odc files: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-HA010167227.aspx#BMlearn_about_data_connections

Comment: Thanks. 'You also need to make sure they actually have access to the cube with their username.' How should I make sure they can access the cube with their windows login and password? Is this something to set up in SSAS? I used windows authentication to developed the cube and connect to SSAS server. What else I need to set up?

Comment: You as an admin will have access to the cube.  Unless you would like to share your username and password with them, you will need to [set up roles and add your intended users as members](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2776/configuring-permissions-for-sql-server-analysis-services/). If you have a lot of users, I suggest using and Active Directory group rather than adding the users individually.